# Link two process in Erlang?

Tags: erlang

To exchange data,it becomes important to link the process first.The following code does the job of linking two processes.

```
start_link(Name) ->
gen_fsm:start_link(?MODULE, [Name], []).
```

My Question : which are the two processes being linked here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example, the process that called `start_link/1` and the process being started as `(?MODULE, Name, Args)`.

It is a mistake to think that two processes need to be linked to exchange data. Data *links the fate of the two processes*. If one dies, the other dies, unless a system process is the one that starts the link (a "system process" means one that is trapping exits). This probably isn't what you want. If you are trying to avoid a deadlock or do something other than just timeout during synchronous messaging if the process you are sending a message to dies before responding, consider something like this:

```
ask(Proc, Request, Data, Timeout) ->
    Ref = monitor(process, Proc),
    Proc ! {self(), Ref, {ask, Request, Data}},
    receive
        {Ref, Res} ->
            demonitor(Ref, [flush]),
            Res;
        {'DOWN', Ref, process, Proc, Reason} ->
            some_cleanup_action(),
            {fail, Reason}
    after
        Timeout ->
            {fail, timeout}
    end.
```

If you are just trying to spawn a worker that needs to give you an answer, you might want to consider using `spawn_monitor` instead and using its `{pid(), reference()}` return as the message you're listening for in response.

As I mentioned above, the process starting the link won't die if it is trapping exits, but you *really* want to avoid trapping exits in most cases. As a basic rule, use `process_flag(trap_exit, true)` as *little* as possible. Getting trap_exit happy everywhere will have *structural* effects you won't intend eventually, and its one of the few things in Erlang that is difficult to refactor away from later.

Comment: Idea behind erlang was to make a fault tolerant system.So if a error dies.let it die and restart it rather than fixing it.So in case if the process dies we need a restarter if i am not wrong?

Comment: Right, but usually you want the called/spawned process to die on its own and let the crashed child just go away. This is the essence of fault tolerance. If you use links everywhere then you are back to having one giant fault space that all crashes together, which is *usually* not what you want. It depends on what sort of boundaries you want to set between elements of your problem solution. When you really need links outside of a supervisor you'll usually know it.

Answer (score 2):

The link is bidirectional, between the process which is calling the function `start_link(Name)` and the new process created by `gen_fsm:start_link(?MODULE, [Name], [])`.

A called function is executed in the context of the calling process.

A new process is created by a spawn function. You should find it in the gen_fsm:start_link/3 code.

When a link is created, if one process exit for an other reason than normal, the linked process will die also, except if it has set `process_flag(trap_exit, true)` in which case it will receive the message `{'EXIT',FromPid,Reason}` where FromPid is the Pid of the process that came to die, and Reason the reason of termination.